# preg_match и Динамический pattern

Tags: php

Вообщем есть такая функция:

```
preg_match('/' . $guid['guid'] . '\_[а-яА-Я\w]+/', $entry)
```

Думаю основная суть понятна она ищет файлы в так скажем строке однако при передаче в $guid['guid'] вот такой строки УТ007569. То она не видит похежести при сравнении с такой строкой УТ007569_SkazkUgolokOtchestvo.xlsx. Она просто не срабатывает я получаю false, но если вставить данный guid статично то всё сработает. Вопрос, как это починить чтобы работало. Вот код который у меня целиком:

```
public function getFile($guid) {
    $arr = [];
    if ($handle = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/client_files')) {
        $i = 0;
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if (preg_match('/' . $guid['guid'] . '\_[а-яА-Я\w]+/', $entry)) {
                $file_name1 = explode("_", $entry);
                array_shift($file_name1);
                $file_name = implode("_", $file_name1);
                $arr[$i]['name'] = $file_name;
                $arr[$i]['href'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/upload/client_files/' . $entry;
                $i++;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: `'/' . $guid['guid'] . '\_[а-яА-Я\w]+/u'` - так работает?

Comment: @ArchDemon нет так тоже не работает

Comment: Не забывайте про [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote.php)

Comment: Какая у вас кодировка в переменной, и в какой сам файл php?

Comment: @vp_arth Кодировка в файле UTF-8, переменная хз, но раз сайт в UTF-8 то и переменная должна быть

Comment: второе неверно, заисит от файловой системы и локали. Потому что readdir. Нужно проверить

Comment: @vp_arth Ну mb_detect_encoding() сказал что везде UTF-8

Comment: Чему равен `strlen($guid['guid'])`? И $entry

Comment: @vp_arth Показывает 9

Comment: Простите, $entry важнее, важно понять, что имя файла не обязано следовать настройкам локали в php

Comment: Если `strlen($entry)===mb_strlen($entry)`? тогда модификатор u в регулярке должен работать

Comment: @vp_arth А вот тут ужс, выдало вот это 122526292727292226282934

Comment: Просто их там было много: 12, 25, 26...

Comment: И что это значит??

Comment: Кстати вот это сравнение strlen($entry)===mb_strlen($entry) показывает 1

Comment: Значит самый первый комментарий должен вам помочь. Ну и preg_quote

Comment: А как правильно использовать preg_quote я что-то понять не могу и кстати я уверен, что у меня приходит без символов переменная

Comment: `'/' . preg_quote($guid['guid'], '/') . '_[а-яА-Я\w]+/u'` Слеш перед `_` вероятно лишний

Comment: Ахахаха всё решилось куда проще я просто сделал так trim($guid['guid']) и всё заработало

Comment: Это нечестно, вы же сказали, что strlen == 9. Если там есть пробел, то это точно не utf-8

Comment: Я говорил то, что показывалось информация

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94876/discussion-on-question-by-moonwolf45-preg-match---pattern).